# for Loop is not Working inside Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is working fine for first element but not for the whole table.
how can i iterate this for whole table.
my jquery code is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (i = 0; i <= 42; i++) {
        if (true) {
            $('#mktType').addClass("important blue");
        } else {
            $('#mktType').addClass("important red");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Why are you using `if (true)`? Also elaborate, What do you mean by `first element but not for the whole table`?

Comment: please supply html as well

Comment: Shouldn't it be `var i = 0;`?

Comment: The fact you're using a loop but acting on an element with an `id` is a red flag. You don't have more than one element using the same `id`, right? As that's invalid.

Comment: thst true is for just cheking there i m passing a condition..and by first element i mean it is working only for one row of table.

Comment: @user3575287: Read the comments above again. As it is, this question cannot be usefully answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is a nonsense, you are adding the same classes 42 times to the element with id "mktType".

If you want to add classes to several elements according to a condition, you should :

- Use a class selector instead.
- Use each to apply a funciton to each element you selected.
- Specify a real condition, use it only in loop if it depends on the element itself.

Comment: I want to just iterate that code for whole table..

Comment: Do you mean every cell of the table ? You should use a cell selector instead.

Comment: Not every cell ..one cell of every row whose name is mkt type.

Comment: A cell can not have a name attribute and you can not have multiple element with the same ID.
Just use a class selector and combine it with a cell selector.
Like "tr > td.cellclass"